# How can modify HTTParty gem for using Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tor, socks, torsocks

I want to be able to make requests with HTTParty via the tor. This functionality isn't yet available in HTTParty gem. How can I change modify it to do requests in combination with Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another gem such as [excon](https://github.com/excon/excon)
this gem support http proxy